# R Shiny filter with two inputs

Tags: r, input, shiny

Hello i need help with filtering data by inputs.Alone select input works properly.Im try something like

`output$tbl<-renderTable({subset(data,data$country==input$countryIn||
data$code==input$code)})`

but its not working.I want that  user choose country and then can writte code to textinput and reduce the data area.

```
ui.R
library(shiny)



shinyUI(fluidPage(

titlePanel("This is my website"),  

sidebarLayout(

sidebarPanel(uiOutput(outputId="country"),textInput(inputId="code",label="writte code")),

mainPanel(tableOutput(outputId="tbl"))


))
)
server.R
library(shiny)

id<-1:6
country<-c("Germany","UK","USA","Poland","UK","UK")
code<-c(255,124,234,751,124,326)
data<-data.frame(id,country,code)


shinyServer(

function(input,output)
{
output$country<-renderUI({selectInput(inputId ="countryIn",label="Choose country",choices=unique(data$country))})
output$tbl<-renderTable({subset(data,data$country==input$countryIn)})
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I refactored your code, since it was really hard to read for me. (I also merged the two files into `app.R`, but it's not necessary)

Second: you use the wrong logical operator. There are two problems with using `||` in this case:

1. You need the and `&`, `&&` operator, instead of the or `|`, `||`, since you want to filter by 2 conditions.
2. The longer form evaluates left to right examining only the first element of each vector. This is not what you want, you need to check all elements of the vector if they are equal to the filtering condition.

So you'd write `subset(data, data$country == input$countryIn & data$code == input$code)`, but it's still not gonna work since the default value of `textInput` is an empty string (`""`), which won't yield any results.

So there are two scenarios: When the data is only filtered by the `code`, and another where both filters are in action. You could use an `if` statement for this:

```
  output$tbl <- renderTable( {
    if(input$code == "") subset(data, data$country == input$countryIn)
    else subset(data, data$country == input$countryIn & data$code == input$code)
  })
```

Please note, that you may want to delay validation, since slowly typing into the `textInput` field will refresh the table.

Complete code:

```
library(shiny)

id <- 1:6
country <- c("Germany", "UK", "USA", "Poland", "UK", "UK")
code <- c(255,124,234,751,124,326)
data <- data.frame(id, country, code)


ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("This is my website"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput(outputId="country"),
      textInput(inputId="code",label="writte code")),
    mainPanel(tableOutput(outputId="tbl"))
  )
)

server <- function(input,output) {
  output$country <- renderUI( {
    selectInput(inputId ="countryIn", label="Choose country", choices=unique(data$country))
  })

  output$tbl <- renderTable( {
    if(input$code == "") subset(data, data$country == input$countryIn)
    else subset(data, data$country == input$countryIn & data$code == input$code)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a several ways you can do that. But, the simplest would be to use `if - else` clause as shown below:

```
output$tbl<-renderTable({
        if(input$code == ""){
          subset(data, input$countryIn == data$country)
        } else{
          subset(data, input$code == data$code & input$countryIn == data$country)
        }
      })
```